# List using forms?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.5

I have a question .Iam going to render a list with listbox(choice control) in my view
want to achieve something like this :

[image: List example]

And this is my idea:

In controller iam going to get objects via doctrine,bind them to a form that way Iam going to create array of forms and send them in response.

Is this good or there is better aproach ?

I know how to populate choice list with data from database(using entity field type) but I don't know set current value for specific object can somebody give me example of that ?

Comment: your image is not displayed

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what you worry about? Maybe some code related with your issue? If you  "create array of forms" it sounds a little bit over-complicated to me but then again it's hard to tell as I can't really see what you try to ask :C